# buildout not respecting pinned version

Tags: plone, buildout

Getting this weird error from a a buildot. The buildout is for plone3 and has versions pinned.

```
$ bin/buildout -Nv 
While:
  Initializing.
  Getting section buildout.
  Initializing section buildout.
  Getting option buildout:parts.
  Getting section filestorage.
  Initializing section filestorage.
  Installing recipe collective.recipe.filestorage.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zope.location 0.0
but zope.site 3.9.2 requires 'zope.location>=3.7.0'.
```

If I delete the fake eggs I get

```
$ rm -r fake-eggs/
$ bin/buildout -Nvv
While:
  Initializing.
  Getting section buildout.
  Initializing section buildout.
  Getting option buildout:parts.
  Getting section filestorage.
  Initializing part filestorage.
  Getting section supervisor.
  Initializing section supervisor.
  Getting option supervisor:programs.
  Getting section instance1.
  Initializing section instance1.
  Getting option instance1:eggs.
  Getting section instance.
  Initializing section instance.
  Loading recipe 'plone.recipe.zope2instance==2.7'.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1804, in main
    user_defaults, windows_restart, command)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 252, in __init__
    options = self['buildout']
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1056, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1130, in _initialize
    self._dosub(k, v)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1177, in _dosub
    v = '$$'.join([self._sub(s, seen) for s in v.split('$$')])
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1241, in _sub
    v = self.buildout[section].get(option, None, seen)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1056, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1144, in _initialize
    self.recipe = recipe_class(buildout, name, self)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/csep/src/collective.recipe.filestorage/collective/recipe/filestorage/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    part = self.buildout[part_name]
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1056, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1130, in _initialize
    self._dosub(k, v)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1177, in _dosub
    v = '$$'.join([self._sub(s, seen) for s in v.split('$$')])
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1241, in _sub
    v = self.buildout[section].get(option, None, seen)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1056, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1130, in _initialize
    self._dosub(k, v)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1177, in _dosub
    v = '$$'.join([self._sub(s, seen) for s in v.split('$$')])
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1241, in _sub
    v = self.buildout[section].get(option, None, seen)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1056, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1141, in _initialize
    recipe_class = _install_and_load(reqs, 'zc.buildout', entry, buildout)
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1078, in _install_and_load
    if pkg_resources.working_set.find(req) is None:
  File "/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 474, in find
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req)     # XXX add more info
VersionConflict: (plone.recipe.zope2instance 4.2 (/Users/dylanjay/Projects/download-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2-py2.4.egg), Requirement.parse('plone.recipe.zope2instance==2.7'))
```

So it seems that collective.recipe.filestorage requires plone.recipe.zope2instance. zope2instance is pinned to 2.7 however during the buildout recipe initialistion this version isn't used and 4.2 is picked instead.

If I remove filestorage from parts the buildout works fine, and the annotate shows the version is currently pinned.

Any ideas on how to get out of this or why the version pinning isn't working here?

Answer (score 2):

You probably are using some add-ons with advanced dependency: Using the plone.app.discussion goodversion helped me very often (I don't mean to add also plone.app.discussion product)!

```
[buildout]
...
extends =
    ...
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.discussion/1.0
```

Comment: no I think it's due something wrong with the way zc.buildout and collective.filestorage work together. As previously stated the versions are already pinned. good-py just pins versions. So this would not help.